# Hide images on small sized screens using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

i have the following markup, which uses bootstrap 4, to show text and images, as follow:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <img src="~/img/img1.png" style="height:60.3px;width:750px" class="mx-auto d-block" />
            <p class="span12 pagination-centered" style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">.... </p>
            <p class="span12 pagination-centered" style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">....</p>

            <img src="~/img/img2.png" class="mx-auto d-block" />

            <p class="span12 pagination-centered" style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">....</p>
            <p class="span12 pagination-centered" style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">..../p>


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

now i want to hide the 2 images on small sized screens and keep the text only, so how i can do so using bootstrap 4? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please change the class of the images to this:

```
<img src="~/img/img1.png" style="height:60.3px;width:750px" class="mx-auto d-none d-md-block" />    
<img src="~/img/img2.png" class="mx-auto d-none d-md-block" />
```

Use d-sm-block if you want to show the image on even smaller devices.
[Here](https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/#d-block) is a cheat sheet for bootstrap that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display classes with breakpoints.

> The media queries effect screen widths with the given breakpoint or
>   larger. For example, `.d-lg-none` sets `display: none;` on both `lg` and `xl`
>   screens.

This will hide on mobile, shows only larger than 768px screens. (see on full page view)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" style="height:250px;width:250px" class="mx-auto d-none d-md-block" />
```